# Prompt login via saved google account

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, google-signin

I know how to integrate "Login via google account" in any website. But in some website like zomato always prompt "login via google" account while opening. It shows the list of google accounts I already logged in from the left upper corner of Firefox. I want to know how it can be done. How it can be integrated in any website. Like this https://ibb.co/Q9TZxyC

Comment: Have you ever find the proper integration for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I know how to integrate "Login via google account" in any website. But in some website like zomato always prompt "login via google" account while opening. It shows the list of google accounts I already logged in from the left upper corner of Firefox. I want to know how it can be done. How it can be integrated in any website.

Can this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFrR3kNZiLk) help

Comment: Thanks for the help. But the video describes the coding for "Login via google" which I already have. I am looking for the method how the google account option are popping up. Like this https://ibb.co/Q9TZxyC